# Why are the currentAccessToken permissions empty right after linking user in background?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Parse.com and Facebook for login, and I want the users to share some content to the Facebook. For this I want to know  I'd like to know why the `[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] permission]` returns an empty array right after the following method is called:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser] withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error) {
    if (succeeded) NSLog(@"%@", [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] permissions]); // returns empty array
}];
```

Any ideas? I have implemented the FB SDK pieces of codes in all the three methods in the appDelegate:

- `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

---

**Motivation:** I don't want to redirect the user to the Facebook safari 'already gave permission' page every time he wants to post something to Facebook, if he really gave me the permission really like five seconds ago.

Another part of the story is that I want to maintain access token for email+password users too, but that's related only if the issue is with me registering the permissions, otherwise I think it's just with correctly saving and recovering token.

Comment: Did you every figure this out?  Mine are empty all of a sudden and I have no idea why!

Comment: Hello @Jbryson! Afaik, it was a real bug, fixed with Parse iOS SDK 1.7.3 (at least for me).